# XSD to Java objects using the XJC (JAXB) results in [ERROR] Property "Value" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, xjc

There are a lot of answers related to this but for some reason, I am still confused and unable to get the Java objects for my XSD.

I am trying to create the Java objects from XSD using the `XJC JAXB` but when I run the XJC command it results in the error

`[ERROR] Property "Value" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.`

Hence, based on my research I found that I need to write the binding file so I wrote the binding file but still I am getting the same error which means that I am messing up something in the binding file. As I am unable to make it work even after a lot of try I thought of posting it and getting some solution.

Following is my XSD which is failing as per the XJC command failure message `foo.xsd`:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="DocumentExtensionType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:any namespace="##local" processContents="lax" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:anyAttribute processContents="lax"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Following are the `JAXB` bindings I tried and executed but still results in an error: `foo.xjb`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="foo.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings
            node="//xsd:complexType[@name='DocumentExtensionType']/xsd:sequence/xsd:choice/xsd:any[@namespace='http://checklists.nist.gov/sccf/0.1']">
            <jxb:property name="any2" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

Following is another `JAXB` binding I've tried: `foo.xjb`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          version="2.1">

    <bindings schemaLocation="foo.xsd" version="1.0">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="com.track.doc"/>
        </schemaBindings>    
        <bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='DocumentExtensionType']/xsd:sequence/xsd:any[@namespace='']">
            <property name="any2"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
    
</bindings>
```

Following is the command I am running in my terminal:

`xjc -p "com.track.doc" -d "/Users/batman/Downloads/XSD" -b foo.xjb foo.xsd`

Can someone please guide me what am I doing mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of things finally this code worked for me. However, I posted only a chunk of XSD which was failing when I run this for this small chunk then it works but when I run for the whole XSD it still fails. Not completely sure what's going wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          version="2.1">

    <bindings schemaLocation="foo.xsd" version="1.0">
        <schemaBindings>
            <package name="com.track.doc"/>
        </schemaBindings>    
        <bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='DocumentExtensionType']/xsd:sequence">
            <property name="seq1"/>
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
    
</bindings>
```

Comment: Also, Make sure that your `XSD` file which you are passing as input does not have any field with the `name` as `value`. In my case I had a field with `name = "value"`.
`<xsd:attribute type="xsd:float" name="value" use="optional"/>` I replaced it with `<xsd:attribute type="xsd:float" name="floatValue" use="optional"/>`

Answer (score 0):

One more issue that I noticed in my XSD. If incase you are also having the similar issue then following might help:

Make sure that your XSD file which you are passing as input does not have any field with the name as value.
In my case I had a field with `name = "value"`.

```
<xsd:attribute type="xsd:float" name="value" use="optional"/>
```

I replaced it with

```
<xsd:attribute type="xsd:float" name="floatValue" use="optional"/>
```